# How to grant the permission again to users group which is denied?

Tags: windows-7

I denied all the permissions for `users(Mypc\users) group` in security tab for one of my drives. 
My drive is inaccessible now, even in `Administrator user` the`security` tab is in invisible too.
how can I grant the permission again to my drive??

**Edit:**
Drive D: and E:
[image]

Comment: You need to take the ownership first to `Administrators` group before you can have access to the permission list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
takeown /f <drive> /r /d y
```

Then

```
icacls <drive> /grant administrators:F /T
```

Comment: I tried it but it just works for one of my drives. for the other drives (D:,E:) I encounter `access is denied` error.I run command prompt with `Run as administrator`.

Comment: What type of drives are D and E?

Comment: They are NTFS drives. what to do??

Comment: Ensure that you use these commands from a command prompt using `Run as Administrator`

Comment: I use these commands from a command prompt using `Run as Administrator'. but I encounter `Access is denied` error.